# Change history after async ajax request on Opera 12

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, opera, browser-history

## Introduction

In an older version of Opera (`Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10.3) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16`) there is a problem with history when update the document.location.hash on an ajax request callback.

## Steps to reproduce:

- listen to `hashchange` and log `document.location.hash` and `history.length`
- change `document.location.hash`
- create a GET request to a json
- handle the GET ajax response and change `document.location.hash`
- wait 5 seconds and change `document.location.hash`
- click on the a link on the page that changes `document.location.hash`

## The code:

```js
// listen to hash changes
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  console.log("Updated hash: ", document.location.hash);
  console.log("history.length: ", history.length);
});
var updateHash = function(hash) {
  document.location.hash = hash;
};
// set the first route
updateHash('#start');

// do async request and change route
promise = $.get('http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/PumsGq6');
promise.done(function() {
  updateHash('#done_async');
});

// wait for 5 seconds and change route
setTimeout(function() {
  updateHash('#complete_timeout');
}, 5000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>History change</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#page">set page</a>
</body>

</html>
```

## What's the result in Chrome and Firefox:

```
Updated hash:  #start
history.length:  2
> XHR finished loading: GET "http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/PumsGq6"
Updated hash:  #done_async
history.length:  3
Updated hash:  #complete_timeout
history.length:  4
Updated hash:  #page
history.length:  5
```

## What's the problem —> [Opera 12](http://www.opera.com/download//?os=mac&ver=12.16&local=y):

```
Updated hash: , #start
history.length: , 2
Updated hash: , #done_async
history.length: , 2
Updated hash: , #complete_timeout
history.length: , 3
Updated hash: , #page
history.length: , 4
```

As can be seen in the console output after an async request the **browser history is not changed**, although **the url/hash is updated correctly**. The `setTimeout` is just to validate that the history can be changed in a not synced fashion.

This is causing navigation issues as I can't go back to a point that does not exists in history.

Comment: You keep saying Opera 9.8, but you're using Opera 12.16, one of the last versions of Opera Presto before they switched to using Blink (Opera Blink is currently on version 29). Is there a specific reason why this needs to work in an outdated version of a browser?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter we are both right, I say 12.16, in fact that's the link I provided, since when you see the user agent for that version it states Opera 9.8. I need to support this version of Opera, it's not possible to update in this case (it's a Sony SmartTV 2014).

Comment: The "9.8" was left in there for historical reasons when Opera moved beyond version 10 (because some idiotic scripts would otherwise consider it to be version 1... don't ask). So the version is 12.16 - might help to update your question to clarify for anyone with the relevant knowledge. Fair enough if it's a TV, guess you can't just set it to auto-update ;-)

Comment: Thank you @AmosM.Carpenter for the clarification, I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't have a full explanation for this it was solved by using jQuery ^1.8.3.